# Append rows in matrix

Tags: matlab

```
for i = 1:6
    if data(i,1) == 1
        disp(i)
        m(i,:) = data(i,:)
    end
end
```

The code above returns a matrix m, with rows of data from the *data* file.

However, data(i,1) == 1 is true 4 times for the particular data, however m has 6 rows. 2 of the rows of m are just full of 0's, but the if statement is only true 4 times.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard MATLAB.

Lets assume `data(1,1)` and `data(3,1)` are 1.

Then `m(1,:)=data(1,:)` and later `m(3,:)=data(3,:)`. But what about `m(2,:)` It has to exist, because you filled `m(3,:)`. There is no 3 without 2!

If you want `m` to have *only* the ones where  `data(i,1) == 1` then do:

```
m=[]; %create empty matrix
for i = 1:6
    if data(i,1) == 1
        disp(i)
        m= [m; data(i,:)]; % "append" to m
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

In answer to "why is that happening", it is because your matrices are the same size, but you only assign values to the rows which satisfy a condition. Therefore leaving other rows as `0`s.

You either need a way to build `m` row by row (see end of this post) or create it in another way (my answer).

---

**You can do this with logical indexing**

```
% For creating m
m = data(data(:, 1) == 1, :);

% For displaying which indices satisfy your condition, one call to disp
disp( find(data(:, 1) == 1) )
```

---

Breaking this down, `m` is assigned to the values of `data`, where the column 1 of `data` is equal to `1`, and all of the columns.

`find` returns the index of any non-zero element. The logical indexing returns an array of `0`s and `1`s, so all elements which satisfy the condition (and are `1`) will be indexed by `find`.

You could also create the logical index and use it twice, better for maintenance at a later date if your condition changes:

```
% create logical index
idx = ( data(:,1) == 1 );

% same as above but using idx
m = data(idx, :);
disp( find(idx) )
```

---

**Documentation**

Logical indexing - https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html

`find` - https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html

---

@Ander's suggestion to append only certain rows will work, and demonstrates well how to build a matrix. However, in this case you do not need your loop and if condition at all.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yours does the job, and changes the least about the OP's code... always more than one way to do something :)